# Gmap.Net Marker at incorrect position but when the map is zoomed the marker goes to right place

Tags: c#, winforms, google-maps, gmap.net

I've a **Windows Forms Application** with a **Gmap.Net** controller, what I want to do is to add markers based on an outside sources that provides locations. The thing is that when I add a marker is initially drawn in an incorrect location, but after I zoom out it goes to the right place. So this is what I got so far:

My Map controller is declare to be located at Panama, Panama.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    //Layer count is just a variable to add new OverLays with different names
    var markersOverlay = new GMapOverlay("markers" + layerCount);

    //Marker far away in Quebec, Canada just to check my point in discussion        
    var marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(58.0032, -79.4957), GMarkerGoogleType.red_small);

    markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker);
    gmap.Overlays.Add(markersOverlay);
    layerCount++;
}
```

So when I press the button what I got is this (have in mind that the map location it's set to be in Panama and the marker in Canada):

[image: First picture without zooming. Source: OC]

And when I zoom out, the marker goes to the correct position in Canada.

[image: Second picture without zooming. Source: OC]

Why my marker is been drawn in Panama initially?

**P.D**: I already check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30636745/gmap-marker-is-placed-in-wrong-position) but it doesn't resolve my problem because I need to be adding more than 1 marker and `myMap.UpdateMarkerLocalPosition(marker)` is not a solution for me.

Comment: I got the same problem here and I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: Hi @gm_fernandes, check the answer it worked completely, it's just a problem with the code lines order. You need to first add the Overlay to the map and then the marker to the Overlay.

Comment: But it isn't working with my program, maybe something is missing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because you're adding the marker to the overlay that has not been added to the map's overlays. Try to switch the order of the statements as follows:

```
gmap.Overlays.Add(markersOverlay);
markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker);
```

Answer (score 1):

add a first marker at lat,lon = 0,0. 
you can also make this marker invisible with setting its marker image as 1x1 pixel transparent png image.
first element of the marker do this kind of wrong placement.

Comment: I recon your effort to find a workaround. If you experience the problem mentioned please try to apply the solution given. If that's not working then let's find out why. The problem was imo a problem of order of appliance.